# Linux - set next boot kernel

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, kernel

I have multiple kernels installed. I'm trying to create a script that would temporarily set the the next boot to the stock Ubuntu kernel.

From my online research, I understood that the kernel order is the result of the following command `awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, where the first line is 0.

This is the output when I run the command:

```
root@server150:~# awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg  
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.9.24
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.9.24 (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-81-generic                    # <- I want this
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-81-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

Since I need the fourth line, I ran `grub-reboot 3`.

However, this boots into a memtest.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I create a script that when executed, would always set the next boot to the stock kernel?

PS: I'm eventually doing it in ansible, but since I couldn't find a module for it, I'm using bash.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Are some of these menu entries in a sub menu?

Comment: Yeah, when I reboot the server, it says "ubuntu" "advanced" and "memtest"